# Tomcat server - JBPM - Takes 3 hours to start

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jbpm

I'm trying to deploy the `jBPM 6.1.0.Final` version code using Spring on Tomcat 6.0 server. It is taking more than 3 hours to start the RuntimeManager when server starts. I have used below :

1) Spring integration

2) Added process and task lifecycle listeners

3) Used singleton session strategy

I am not sure why it is taking so much time to deploy. With `JBPM 5.4` it worked just fine.

I have taken the thread dump and memory dump, but there is nothing out of the ordinary.  Are there any other ways I can view exactly which threads are hogging the time?

EDIT - Java version 6, Tomcat version 6

Comment: `top -H` is a pretty easy place to start, if `jvisualvm` isn't giving you what you want.

Comment: We can't see any of your code, how can we help apart from asking basic troubleshooting questions; 1) Same hardware? 2) Same version of Java? 3) On every restart of the application (or just the first)? 4) Have you checked the logs?

Comment: 0) Does it ever complete, or do you just give up and "pull the plug" after three hours?  1) Tomcat 6.0 is relatively old.  2) You don't even mention which versions of Spring or Java you're using.  Or what platform you're running on.  3) KEY question: clearly something is "waiting"?  4) Q: What *do* the traces you've taken show?  5) Q: What about system statistics? Top or Task Manager?  Do you see high CPU?  Or high memory usage?  *MOST IMPORTANT*: 6) What do the logs show?  What activity (as shown in the log) finally "completes" at the end of three hours???

Comment: Hi @ElliottFrisch, the source code here is not the issue because it's the entire JBPM workflow.  1) Hardware is the same, 2) Java version is the same, 3) On every restart, 4) Logs are clean, it just gets stuck at a point.  We put some Logs where we suspected it might be causing time, but that isn't the issue.

Comment: Java version 6 is EOL, Java version 7 is EOL in April. Why are you "upgrading" to such old versions?

Comment: @FoggyDay, Added the java and tomcat versions.  We are monitoring thread dumps and memory dumps only for now.  As mentioned by you and Paul Hicks, we are trying the top -H command.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, We are stuck with Java 6 for now, it's not our call to decide the upgrades.

Comment: Perhaps not, but it is presumably within your remit to identify the use of unsupported software.

Comment: "it just gets stuck at a point"  YOUR MISSION IS TO FIGURE OUT JUST WHAT THAT "POINT" IS.  Your best bet is 1) monitor system performance (e.g. "top" for Linux, or "Task Mgr" for Windows).  Check for a spike in CPU usage, or a spike in memory usage.  Or, equivalently, check for a sudden *drop* in CPU usage (maybe startup is waiting for something?)  2) Monitor logs.  What happens immediately *before* the "hang"?  What happens immediately after the "hang" clears?

Comment: @FoggyDay, that's correct, we are trying to monitor the systems.  If there are any tools that might help us, please suggest.  Thanks.

Comment: For starters, just type "top" in a console window, and watch what happens when you start the system.  "top" updates CPU, memory, I/O and process statistics continuously.  You can literally "watch what happens".  In real time.  You can read more here: http://tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/system-resources.html

Comment: We have zeroed down to a possible cause.  `Failed to read schema document 'http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI-XMI', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsdchema>.` is showing up regularly in the logs and taking some time.  I will update once I get some more information.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, everyone.  A big lesson learnt and documented through StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue has been identified.  The bottle neck was with `http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524` namespace.  There were several such namespaces included in the BPM XML file for XSD.  But they weren't getting loaded.  The root cause is an Eclipse plugin bug for BPMN2 plugin that generates incorrect XSD definitions in the XML file.  By removing all XSD definitions except `BPMN2.0.xsd` it started correctly.

Comment: If anyone needs any details, please post questions/comments here, I will be glad to answer.